# What is basically at stake in contemporary discussions regarding essentialism and essential properties?

Tags: modal-logic, essence

- Modern discussions of " essentialism" ( 17th century) can be associated with the empiricism / rationalsit debate. By denying that we have acces to " real essences" , Locke also denies that we can know things independently of sensible experience. I cannot know the properties of gold *a priori*, for that would require me to first possess a concept of the essence of gold. But my concept only refers to the " nominal essence" of this metal.
- Now what is at stake in contemporary ( 20th-21 st. century) discussions regarding essentialism ( Quine, Lowe, Fine, Kripke, etc) ?
- I have a couple of ideas, rather vague though.

(1) epistemological concerns : essentialism could provide a ground for scientific realism

(2) semantic concerns : essentialism could provide a ground for modal logic

- In brief, what  makes " essentialism" a philosophically hot question nowadays? What are the expected theoretical gains of essentialism?

Comment: Who would be discussing this contemporarily? Any names in mind, specific papers of debate?

Comment: Quine, Lowe, Kripke, Fine, etc.

Comment: Have you read a page of Kripke?

Comment: I'm looking for a good reason to engage in such a reading. Could you point out a passage in which Kripke gives his motivations for discussing essentialsim?

Comment: I've read this : http://encyclo-philo.fr/essence-a/

Comment: "Naming and necessity" is a great book in which Kripke argues for a form of essentialism throughout. That's metaphysics and can be enjoyed as such. Like a painting by van Gough. However, it's all irrelevant for the natural sciences. On the other hand: Quine's holistic naturalism is very relevant for the understanding of science.

Comment: You guessed right, it is about [natural kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/#Ess) and [*de re* necessity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possible-worlds/#Applications).

Comment: Debates about essentialism are often related to debates about whether there are [natural kinds](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-kind/)--see esp. the discussion in [this section](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-kind/#SH2a) of the IEP article. For example, if one sees classification into biological species as merely pragmatic but thinks there is no objective way to mark the exact point where one species transitions to another in evolution, that would be a non-essentialist way of viewing species, while if one believes in an objective truth about every organism's species that would be essentialistic.